# Banach Spaces: Totally Bounded vs. Bounded

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Are the finite dimensional Banach spaces precisely those ones in which subsets are totally bounded iff they're bounded?

Comment: Normed spaces only, or general topological vector spaces?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hmm, let it be for the first 'only' a normed vector space...

Comment: Terry Tao has a nice blog on a proof of this for general Hausdorff topological vector spaces ("locally compact topological vector spaces").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming a normed space $X$ based on your comments.

If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space, then there exists a sequence $\{ x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of unit vectors such that $\|x_{m}-x_{n}\| \ge 1/2$ for all $n \ne m$. That's a consequence of the Riesz lemma. I think that answers your question.

Comment: Ditto for Hausdorff topological vector spaces, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma.

Comment: Aaah, I got confused what I really wanted: There can be totally bounded subsets in an infinite dimensional space - what makes a space infinite dimensional however is that there's also a bounded subset that is *not* totally bounded... I will put a more specific question on these subtleties later (if you want to I can let you know). Anyway, thanks for the *easy* answer ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S : Yes, the Riesz lemma shows that the unit ball of an infinite-dimensional normed space is not totally bounded, even though it is clearly bounded.

Comment: Btw, how does one prove that bounded sets are totally bounded in finite dimensional Banach spaces?

Comment: @Freeze_S, a bounded set has bounded closure, which is compact, thus totally bounded, and a subset of a totally bounded set is totally bounded

Comment: @Freeze_S : Adding to what JHance had to say, a set $K$ in a metric space is compact iff $K$ is complete and totally bounded.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yepp ;)

Comment: @JHance: And how to prove compactness of closed bounded set in a finite dimensional Banach space?

Comment: @JHance: The point is that I guess the proof goes to show that every sequence posseses a subsequence that is cauchy and therefore convergent by completeness. So a bounded closed subset is compact; but the core here was to actually prove that a bounded subset is totally bounded and the rest is (merely) the equivalence T.A.E. pointed out... or? What do you think?